# Run Android Gradle Managed Device on Gitlab CI

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gitlab-ci

Locally it works correct, but on Gitlab CI I have the error:

[image]

Device config:

```
testOptions {
    managedDevices {
        devices {
            illusionDevice (com.android.build.api.dsl.ManagedVirtualDevice) {
                device = "Pixel 2"
                apiLevel = 30
                systemImageSource = "aosp-atd"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Indirect shaders property is enabled:

```
android.testoptions.manageddevices.emulator.gpu=swiftshader_indirect
```

My test project - https://gitlab.com/illuzor/gradle-manager-devices-test

Failed build -  https://gitlab.com/illuzor/gradle-manager-devices-test/-/jobs/3656625078

Is it possible to find out the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to run gradle managed devices on gitlab ci or github actions.
Agents are runs on x86 on docker. Emulator with x86 requires acceleration. Docker can't use hardware acceleration.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-accel-restrictions

Comment: MacOs under Github works with hardware acceleration. Or consider to use self-hosted runner!

Comment: Yes, it's possible in GitLab CI and we are doing it without issues. Your runner, where you load docker, has to support KVM.

Answer (score 1):

Your runner has to support KVM (Kernel-based Virtual Machine). You can check whether it supports it with `kvm-ok` command.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Android Gradle ManagedVirtualDevice on GitHub Actions.

MacOS build agent is required.
Additional `animationsDisabled = true` is added to the `testOptions`.

My test project - https://github.com/siarhei-luskanau/android-managed-virtual-device

Success build - https://github.com/siarhei-luskanau/android-managed-virtual-device/actions/runs/5970333166

Comment: Can you explain, why macos is required? I can`t find info about it in docs https://developer.android.com/studio/test/gradle-managed-devices

Comment: I have managed to run Android emulator on MacOS build agent only on GitHub Actions. May be there are restrictions with nested virtualization.

Comment: @SiarheiLuskanau Actions run expired, pls edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am faced with exact same issue locally and fixed it by removing all managed devices:

```bash
./gradlew cleanManagedDevices
```